# Get list of parameter names from native sql expression (regex)

Tags: java, sql, regex

I'm having trouble getting list of all parameters in SQL query using Regex.

Example of the query:

```
SELECT ... WHERE col1 = :user AND col2 = 'HELLO' OR col3 = :language
```

To obtain parameters, I use following regex pattern:

```
Pattern.compile(":([\\w.$]+|\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+')", Pattern.MULTILINE)
```

The pattern returns list of parameters correctly:

```
:user
:language
```

The problem is with another type of query, where literals might contain character ':'

```
WHERE col1 = :user AND some_date > '2022-09-26T10:22:55'
```

The list of parameters for this case is:

```
:user
:22
:55
```

Is there any better approach that will not consider contents of literals as parameters?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[^'\":]*:([\\w.$]+|\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+')", Pattern.MULTILINE)`

Comment: Thanks for response. But in scenario: `code <> '*'\nAND code IN (select x from ... where user = :user)` it considers `\nAND code IN (select x from ... where user = :user` to be parameter.

Comment: `Pattern.DOT_ALL` will let the `.` also match newlines. Forgotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your problem by assuming that a named param in sql is just a word with prefix `:` and always follows after a space (this is actually not a requirement or always true but might be just good enough to get you acceptable results with as simple of regex as possible)

```
Pattern.compile(" :\\w+", Pattern.MULTILINE)
```

--

summary of the comments:

```
had to match 
- foo = :param AND :param = bar AND foo=:param AND :param=bar
- AND FUNC(:param) OR FUNC(0, :param) OR FUNC(:param, 0)
```

finally this regex with fixed length lookahead and variable length lookbehind was helpful:

```
 Pattern.compile("(?<=[=(])\\s*:[\\w_.]+|:[\\w_.]+(?=\s*[=)])", Pattern.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As much as I wish I could, I can't. In my queries, there are parameters containing "_" or "." as well and might not be prefixed with whitespace. Unfortunately I'm not able to affect it as the sql query is somehow extrernaly generated.

Comment: what's about `Pattern.compile("(?<==) ?:[\\w_.]+, Pattern.MULTILINE)` using regex lookbehind and assuming the param is followed after a `=`

Comment: Well the parameter is not always after = operator. You can have scenario where `:parameter = 'ABC'` (inversed).

Comment: So it's a lookbehind or lookahead. (lookbehind must be fixed length... can't include variable with space there) `(?<==)\s*:[\w_.]+|:[\w_.]+(?=\s*=)` see https://rubular.com/r/BmGCgJdZ4bZFkR

Comment: This one works better, but I'm still facing issues with function calls `AND FUNC(:param) OR FUNC(0, :param) OR FUNC(:param, 0)` Edit: The regex I've used has been matching everything propertly, but somehow yours does properly ignore literals. https://rubular.com/r/uZ9BsgOqpU0KkH

Comment: could be included like this: `(?<=[=(])\s*:[\w_.]+|:[\w_.]+(?=\s*[=)])` see  https://rubular.com/r/xbQ1DhhTavy1M5 (only works if param is first or last arg in func)